# How to use third party library by cocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I install a Third party Library by it successfully.
[image]

i try to use the third party library.So i code in RootViewController.h:

```
#import "DDCollectionViewFlowLayout.h"
```

the error occurs:

```
DDCollectionViewFlowLayout.h file not found
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is out of the third party library.
I tried use AFNetworking by cocoaPods and write code:

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

it works well.